# I'm having issues importing ViewPager with Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to import a project into Android Studio. I'm getting weird errors.

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'library'
Information:Compilation completed with 100 errors and 5 warnings in 26 sec
Error:(31, 31) java: package android.support.v4.view does not exist
/Users/clxxxii/Downloads/JakeWharton-ViewPagerIndicator-8cd549f/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/TitlePageIndicator.java
```

In the class TitlePageIndicator, these imports aren't working.

```
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

Android studio recognizes android.support.v4.view. but not ViewPager, ViewConfigurationCompat nor MotionEventCompat. Do you know what the problem could be?

///////

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':android-sdks:extras:google:google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':Downloads:Android Group Chat App using Sockets:android-websockets-master')
    compile project(':Downloads:JakeWharton-ViewPagerIndicator-8cd549f:library')
    compile project(':Downloads:BaseGameUtils')
    compile project(':Downloads:polljoy-android-master:PolljoySDK')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: add this in your build.gradle ...:  compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0"

Comment: add `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'` to your `dependencies`

Answer (score 4):

Your gradle.build file is missing these:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Migrate Project to Gradle?
           This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.
           More Information about migrating to Gradle
           Don't show this message again.